# How to speed up Google Translate

Tags: api, google-translate

I have a web page that has 70000 characters. As you know when doing translation through Google API you can only send up to 5000 characters at a time. Which means I have to send data to Google 14 times (70000/5000) which takes a lot of time and then my page is displayed. Is there a way to speed up the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried caching the translation?

Comment: Yes that's what I have been thinking. But I was wondering how am I going to implement it. My site has more than 1 million pages and I was thinking that when a user requests a page then my script will check if that page already exists. If the page already exists and is less than 5 minutes old then it will display it from that cache otherwise it will fetch a new copy from Google Translate. So each page will be displayed for 5 minutes from cache after which it will be refreshed.

Comment: wow 1M pages... you have to give more information about the context, how the pages are generated, how much traffic, what is the content of the pages (you have to translate all?), etc. Then you can think of the best approach of caching or whatever.

Comment: The site is in PHP and database is MySQL. All pages are dynamic and are generated after fetching information from database. I want to translate all pages but not all at a time. Because no one will visit all pages at once so I want to translate pages on the fly when they are requested.

Comment: AFAIK google translate forbids automatic queries. So your 5 minutes cache strategy seems undoable. I still don't get your use case, you need plain text translation like translating a book or is more like a localization problem?

Comment: I didn't get this automatic queries? My case is simple. I have a website say www.stackoverflow.com and I want to have another subdomain cn.stackoverflow.com for Chinese users which will display same content as main domain but in Chinese. I don't want to use frames or that Google toolbar unless there is someway to hide it and do translation automatically on page load!? Because toolbar translates content after it has been loaded in browser and user has to select language from drop down list.

Comment: oh I see... well I think one way is doing a 'progresive' translation of the parts of the pages, via ajax calls, when the user reaches some part of the page. As the user scrolls down the page you submit the next 'section' to be displayed and send that to google translate, updating the result.

Comment: Yeah I am already doing this now. And now close to fix that 5000 chars problem although again not perfectly but still somewhat acceptable.

Comment: yeah, your use-case is quite demanding for the google translate limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using some AJAX framework (you don't mention what your web page is created with eg c#) then you can make it faster by making the API call via the AJAX framework.

It would look something like this (psuedo-code since we don't know what you are using):

```
Serve web page (almost instant)
Web page starts AJAX call:
    Break text into chunks
    Foreach chunk
        Translate via API
        Append to the page
```

This way the user will see the page immediately, and will also see the translation appear piece by piece as it is processsed instead of having to wait until the end.

Comment: I am using PHP and that's what I also thought and tried to use it but I didn't want to change existing code as there are a lot of pages. So what I am doing right now is, I fetch HTML of my page through file_get_contents and then I send that HTML to Google (5000 characters at a time).

Comment: AFAIK 5K is a limit even with AJAX API, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be to generate a page in one language, then ask google to translate it trough HTTP and display result as your own, to make it seamless for user. I believe that is what Google Chrome does when translating web pages.

Example of URL that makes Google translate the whole web page:

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Flinux.org.ru%2F

Of course, another option is to use Google Translate API and cache result if page content is not changing frequently.

Answer (score -1):

go to the Javascript file in Google, it will lead you also to the CSS file, make a file or perhaps two, or you may be able to add CSS to your own, now make Javascript page on your web site in own directory.  make a nip of code to update the Javascript code every so many seconds or minutes, and this will make the transition much faster, just by refreshing the content they give.. have fun :)  also ultimately you can also send a request at the same time as the first one to translate after char 5000 which should be relatively easy to do.